# How to add hovers for amCharts Guides?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

In amCharts Area Chart, is it possible to add Balloon for the Guides similar to below? The requirement is to show more information about vertical line when user hovers over it.

[image]

Comment: JSFiddle for convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/5pdunxqf/1/

Comment: I have no idea how I got to this question, but I've edited the question to include the JavaScript tag to give it a lot more visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You should add balloonText to the guide object, not like you did but like this:

```
        "guides": [{
        category: "2001",
        toCategory: "2003",
        lineColor: "#CC0000",
        lineAlpha: 1,
        fillAlpha: 0.2,
        fillColor: "#CC0000",
        dashLength: 2,
        inside: true,
        labelRotation: 90,
        label: "fines for speeding increased",
        "balloonText": "<img src='http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/car.png' style='vertical-align:bottom; margin-right: 10px; width:28px; height:21px;'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>asaassssss</b></span>",
    }, {
        category: "2007",
        lineColor: "#CC0000",
        lineAlpha: 1,
        dashLength: 2,
        inside: true,
        labelRotation: 90,
        label: "motorcycle fee introduced"
    }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5pdunxqf/2/

Comment: Just as an addition: the balloonText only shows when you move the cursor above the chart, on top of the guide. If you want to display the balloonText when you hover over the chart ànd guide, you need to set one property to true:     above: true
This displays the guide above the chart(s) and then you may hover every part of the guide to show the balloonText.